# DataTables columnFilter number-range filtering

Tags: php, sql, filter, datatables, datatables-1.10

I have database where in column `"BIRTH_DATE"` there is date (for example `2015-06-26`). I use `DataTables` to display information for users. I want to make number range search. But when I am using `DataTables` plugin `ColumnFilter` and try to use `number-range` type filter it doesn't works.

As soon as I enter any value to `from` or `to` field it tells me that there are no results. But if in same column there is a row where date is written like that `20150626` filter shows it. So as I understand problem is in symbol `-` in middle of my number. How could I make filter ignore `-` sign?

Number-Range filter code:

```
function fnCreateCharRangeInput() {

        th.html(_fnRangeLabelPart(0));
        var sFromId = sTableId + 'range_from_' + i;
        var from = $('<input type="text" class="number_range_filter" id="' + sFromId + '" rel="' + i + '"/>');
        th.append(from);
        th.append(_fnRangeLabelPart(1));
        var sToId = sTableId + 'range_to_' + i;
        var to = $('<input type="text" class="number_range_filter" id="' + sToId + '" rel="' + i + '"/>');
        th.append(to);
        th.append(_fnRangeLabelPart(2));
        th.wrapInner('<span class="filterColumn filter_number_range" />');
        var index = i;
        aiCustomSearch_Indexes.push(i);



        //------------start range filtering function


        /*  Custom filtering function which will filter data in column four between two values
        *   Author:     Allan Jardine, Modified by Jovan Popovic
        */
        $.fn.dataTableExt.afnFiltering.push(
            function (oSettings, aData, iDataIndex) {
                var iMin = document.getElementById(sFromId).value * 1;
                var iMax = document.getElementById(sToId).value * 1;
                var iValue = aData[index] == "-" ? 0 : aData[index] * 1;
                if (iMin == "" && iMax == "") {
                    return true;
                }
                else if (iMin == "" && iValue < iMax) {
                    return true;
                }
                else if (iMin < iValue && "" == iMax) {
                    return true;
                }
                else if (iMin < iValue && iValue < iMax) {
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        );
        //------------end range filtering function



        $('#' + sFromId + ',#' + sToId, th).keyup(function () {

            var iMin = document.getElementById(sFromId).value * 1;
            var iMax = document.getElementById(sToId).value * 1;
            if (iMin != 0 && iMax != 0 && iMin > iMax)
                return;

            oTable.fnDraw();

        });


    }
```

EDIT:2015-06-29

Or maybe somebody could help me to make this filter ignore input format just run simple action like for example:

```
Select * from table where BIRTH_DATE between '2010' and '2011-12'
```

Because query like that works fine in sql.

Answer (score 3):

I have also faced the problem:

There might be two reasons:

**1)**    Value of `iMin`,`iMax`, `iValue` must be in
    seconds means in `number of milliseconds since 1970/01/01` check
    this [getTime()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_gettime.asp)

**eg**

```
var iMin = document.getElementById(sFromId).value
```

Because for comparison `(iMin == "" && iValue < iMax)` you are using arithmetic operators (`=,<,>`) so value of these three variable must be numeric.

**2)**  Please confirm this first: I guess your date format is like this `2015-06-26` You have to convert date to this format `2015/06/26` to make it work. Not sure why but in some cases jquery doesn't accept  `1970-01-01` and `1970/01/01` works perfectly.

**Have a look on my function**

```
$.fn.dataTableExt.afnFiltering.push(
      function(oSettings, aData, iDataIndex) {
        if(chart.XminDate != '' && chart.XmaxDate !=  ''){
            minDateFilter = new Date( chart.XminDate.replace(/\-/g,'/') ).getTime();
            maxDateFilter = new Date( chart.XmaxDate.replace(/\-/g,'/') ).getTime();
            aData._date = new Date( aData[3].replace(/\-/g,'/') ).getTime();
            if (minDateFilter) {
                if (aData._date < minDateFilter) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            if (maxDateFilter) {
                if (aData._date > maxDateFilter) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
        return true;
      }
    );
```

In my function

```
 var iMin = document.getElementById(sFromId).value * 1; /*same as chart.XminDate */
 var iMax = document.getElementById(sToId).value * 1; /*same as chart.XmaxDate */
 var iValue = aData[index] == "-" ? 0 : aData[index] * 1; /*same as aData._date */
```

In this line

```
 minDateFilter = new Date( chart.XminDate.replace(/\-/g,'/') ).getTime();
```

I have replaced `-` with `/` after this I have created a date object and then I have used `getTime()` function on it to get `number of milliseconds since 1970/01/01`

So I guess(*as I have no idea about your HTML*) This will help you.

Answer (score 1):

What is the type of your column `BIRTH_DATE`?

My advice would be to make it a `datetime` (something looking like `2015-06-26 16:10:18.820`, although it can also be without the precise hour).
Datatables can sort by `datatime` if you set your column type to `date`.

See here for a more detailled description of column.type in DataTables https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.type

Comment: My column `BIRTH_DATE` is `varchar` type. And I cannot change it because I'm getting big packs of new data every day and in the data that I receive `BIRTH_DATE` column is `varchar`. If I change it I will have to do it every time when I want to upload new data.

Comment: Date columns will accept string dates in the insert so it does not matter that what you receive is listed as varchar, just input that and MySQL will insert it into a DATE column. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/datetime.html

Comment: And DO NOT listen to anyone who tells you to store dates in anything but DATE or DATETIME columns, As soon as you do that you can not use the built in date functions and end up with problems like this. Also, datatables does not care what the data is stores as in a database, it is all strings in html. It only matters that the format is correct for the daterange filter to work.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `number-range` try `date-range`.
[See example here](https://jquery-datatables-column-filter.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/dateRange.html)

Comment: Tried alredy. First of all date-range doesn't works at all for me. Second - I need input to be text-field not date picker

Answer (score 0):

First, run an update in your database to your table to delete the "-" in the `birth_date` column if needed.

Second, create a trigger in your database before insert that formats the `BIRTH_DATE` varchar to the desired format.

Then you will be able to filter with your initial `number_range` search in the `datatable`.

But, like Mazet said, it would be better to use datetime for the best query performance. If this is not possible, then you have my quick workaround above.